# PHP strtotime giving the wrong date for certain months

Tags: php, strtotime

the following code.

```
strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month"));
```

Is working correctly but with the months of April `+2 month`, October `+ 8 month`, and December `+ 10 month` is giving the second saturday in that month not the first.

Any ideas what is causing it and how to stop it.

Marvellous

Comment: what you get if u do strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("1 April 2011"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$saturday = strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime(date("01-m-Y"))));
```

Comment: Marvellous. Simple and effective just what I wanted.

Comment: @butterbrot If `strtotime("+2 month", strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))` is a Saturday, **you're still going to get the next**.

Comment: true, strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month", strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))-1); will that do?

Comment: @butterbrot No. This, too, can be a saturday. You'll need to check if `"+2 month"` is a saturday first. Like in my answer...

Comment: @linus no not sure, if `strtotime("+2 month", strtotime(date("01-m-Y")))-1` is a saturday as well, it is the wrong saturday as it is in the pref month, and we care about the next month. (?)

Comment: having said that, this should probably work too: `strtotime("first saturday", strtotime("+2 month last day", $now))`

Answer (score 1):

This is because "first saturday" is calculate *from* the date given. If given date already is a saturday, the next one is calculated.

If you need the first saturday from a specific month, do:

```
$stamp = time();
$tm = localtime($stamp, TRUE);

// +1 to account for the offset, +2 for "+2 month"
$begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, $tm['tm_mon'] + 1 + 2, 1, 1900 + $tm['tm_year']);

if (6 == $begin['tm_wday']) {
//  we already got the saturday
    $first_saturday = $stamp;
} else {
    $first_saturday = strtotime('first saturday', $begin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first day of the month to create your origin timestamp, and then just check the month/year:

```
function firstSaturday($month, $year) {
    if (!is_numeric($month) && !is_numeric($year)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return strtotime('first saturday', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
}
```